# How to mock a connection using nock library?

Tags: node.js, testing, nock

I have application code that verifies `response.connection.remoteAddress` isn't a local IP, but when using nock `response.connection` is just an EventEmitter instance with no `remoteAddress` property. How do I modify response that nock creates?

Update:
I ended up mocking isPrivate() instead:

```
it('GET returns a 403 status code when example.com resolved to internal ip', function(done){
    const scope = nock('https://example.com')
    .get('/some/fetched/url')
    .replyWithFile(200, FILE_CONTENT);

    spyOn(ip, 'isPrivate').and.callFake(() => {
        return true;
    });

    // this handler fetches a url, we want to throw an error if it
    // resolves to an internal IP
    fetch(`${env.testHost}/some-url-under-test`).then(function(response){
        response.text().then(function(body){
            scope.done();
            expect(response.status).toBe(403);
            expect(body).toEqual('Forbidden');
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the expected value given that it's a mocked request with no remote address to reference?

Comment: In my test I want to set it to a local IP and verify my handler returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

Node's `http.ClientRequest.connection` is an [alias](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_connection) for `socket`. The current version of Nock doesn't properly set the `connection` alias (it was [recently fixed](https://github.com/nock/nock/pull/1590), but has yet to be released), however, it does properly create a dummy socket that is [shared between the request and the response](https://github.com/nock/nock/blob/cb56669e0bee13dfa9c668ecb3d0efb714f6240c/lib/request_overrider.js#L127) on the `socket` attribute.

Keep in mind the dummy `Socket` object doesn't have a remote `remoteAddress` attribute, but you should be able to add one between creating the request and calling `end`.

```
req.socket.remoteAddress = '127.0.0.1'
req.end()
```

Comment: How do I access the request in my test from the returned nock scope?

Comment: How/where you update the request is dependant on the test setup itself. Could you update your question with a basic version of your test? Keep in mind that Nock Scopes don't point directly to requests. Usually, you're creating the request as part of the test.